# Choosing Number of Points and PPI Resolution To Future-Proof Game Images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, ios, ppi, apple

I'm working on an iOS SpriteKit game and I'm currently designing some images to be used as character animations in Photoshop. There are many different iPhones with various screen sizes and resolutions, because of this designers generally have to create assets in 1,2,3x multiples.

I've read a few [design articles](https://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/) that suggest to use design your assets/images at 1x  points with a small resolution like 72 and then scale it up by a multiple like 2x or 3x for higher resolution devices (like those with a Retina display).

Why would this be the suggested route, won't this cause blurring every time we scale up? Would it not instead make sense to work with a very high resolution PPI or maybe even use something like vector graphics in Photoshop?

Thanks for any help in clearing up my confusion.

Comment: There's no currently-supported iPhone without a retina screen. The first was the iPhone 4 in 2010.

Comment: @Tetsujin the question is really about what the best practice is currently for creating assets/images to future-proof them? Like if there is a standard resolution that one should aim for etc and then scale the image down or up for 1x, 2x, 3x

Comment: This might be a better ask over at gamedev. I suspect the answer is going to be "define a logical unit" and work in those units. "PPI" is a red herring here though.